# Razor, HTML, jQuery: How to check/uncheck all checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html, razor, checkbox

I have the following code in **Razor and HTML**:

```
    @:<td>   
           <input class="privcheck"
              type="checkbox"
              name="selectedPrivileges"
              value="@priv.PrivilegeID"
             @(Html.Raw(priv.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
           @priv.PrivilegeName

    @:</td>

<button id="checkallprivs">
   Select All
</button>

<button id="uncheckallprivs">
    Deselect All
</button>
```

And the following **jquery**:

```
$("#checkallprivs").button();
$("#uncheckallprivs").button();

$(document).on("click", "#checkallprivs", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('.privcheck:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');

                });

$(document).on("click", "#uncheckallprivs", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('.privcheck:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
                });
```

When I click the "Select All" button, it checks all the boxes. After that, if I click "Deselect All" it unchecks all the checkboxes. The issue however is that once i click on the deselct button, the Select All button does not do anything when clicked. How can I get the expected behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `.prop('checked', false)` instead of `removeAttr(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`

```
$(document).on("click", "#checkallprivs", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.privcheck:checkbox').prop('checked', true);

});

$(document).on("click", "#uncheckallprivs", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.privcheck:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```